# Redirect rule to change url parameters with slashes / in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I  need to change url parameters with slashes.

My current working url is

```
https://www.example.com/Blog-Details.php?blog=test-title
```

I need to change it like below

```
https://www.example.com/Blog-Details.php/blog/test-title
```

My htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+).html $1.php
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+).html $1.php
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(.*)\.html /market_material.php?ind=$3
#RewriteRule ^([A-Z]{2})/([\+a-z\ ]+)\.html$ /reports_content.php?
report_id=$1 
#RewriteRule ^report/([0-9]+) /reports_content.php?report_id=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html /reports_content.php?report_id=$1
#RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+) /Blog-Details.php?blog=$1
#RewriteRule ^Blog-Details.html/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?blog=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ /Blog-Details.html?p=$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

I added this line to convert parameters with slashes

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ /Blog-Details.html?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following RewriteRule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} blog=(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/Blog-Details.php/%1? [R=301, NC, L]
```

This is grabbing your variable `blog=` using a condition and then adding it onto the end of your URL using `%1`. You'll notice I've also added a `?` onto the end of the RewriteRule, this is to stop the original query string from appearing on the end of the URL.

The rewrite works by using 301 redirection, you might want to change this to 302 to make it a temporary redirect while testing.

Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

Comment: I got Internal Server Error 500